# How to transform my Excel table so the column name is now a value of its own?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have this table below: 
[image: Table 1]

What I want to do is to transform/transpose it to be like this:
[image: Table 2]

Anyone knows how to do this? I know this can be done by PowerQuery, but I can't figure out which function I should use. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Pivot is the command you want. Give Google a spin and you'll find many, many tutorials showing you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Load the table into the Query editor, select the first column and then click the ribbon command "Unpivot other columns". Rename the resulting columns as desired.